# VB compile error and which reference should be import

Tags: vb6

```
TagPath = Left$(CurDir, 2) & "\his\users\program\"
```

[image]

hello, everyone. When I run start VB program use VB6.0 have a error message “compile error：can't find project or library” and target is about CurDir, but I don't know what reference need to be import. I'm very appreciate it if someone could help me. thank you very much.

Comment: Honestly, porting vb6 you are more than likely going to hit this type of thing more and more.  You would be far better off converting this to use the vb.net version of these functions rather than to try and import some backwards compatible library.  That said you will find some vb6 functionality in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic?view=net-6.0

Comment: Is this a VB6 question or a VB.NET question? It seems to be the former but the question is only tagged with the latter.

Comment: it's VB question, thx for your comment

Comment: @ericsjz VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: Just for my on clarification, are you trying to migrate a VB6 project to .Net or have I miss-understood the question?

Comment: Run VB6 as administrator.

Comment: Check the references (`Project-References`) to see if there are any missing/unresolved libraries.  This may not be related to `CurDir`, which is a member of `VBA.FileSystem` which resides in the VB runtime library (C:\Windows\System32\msvbvm60.dll - or SysWOW64 for a 64bit system); it would be unusual for that dll not to be present.